# Which cement to use on a fountain

Tags: waterproofing

can someone tell me the correct cement to use on an exterior water fountain surface. I am a decorative artist and wish to "texture" a fountain with white cement that I will tint myself. I'm thinking it should be Portland cement but would like your confirmation on that.

Answer (score 1):

I have built 3 or 4 fountains, all have been poured with "ready mix" delivered in huge trucks that haul 9 yards of concrete at a time. Standard mix no special gravel, you usually need to specify the strength you need, whether it is 2500 PSI or up to 5000 PSI

You can special order white concrete if that is what you need. If it is a smaller batch it can be bought in bags too, you will need to add white sand and gravel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get the impression that the OP is looking to put a tinted parge coat on an existing fountain, not pour one from scratch. I could, of course, be wrong.

Comment: @FreeMan, by Jove, you may be right....

Comment: Thanks, t top 2 pics as you may tell are the same fountain. it was going through testing before it was finished. it does now have a stack of 4X3 white oak above the pool. Its inspiration was the locks of C&O canal. Hard to tell now but it turned out really nice. My boss said he wanted the pour done all at one time. it should have been done in 2, but I was able to pull it off